# Tool to migrate files from Dropbox to OneDrive

Tags: dropbox, microsoft-office, migration

My development group has over 1.5TB of files on Dropbox.  Our company is standardizing on Office 365 and OneDrive for files.  I am seeking the best way to migrate the files from Dropbox to our OneDrive, correcting any naming issues in the process.

Ideally, this could be a tool which we could use both for the big migration and also individual users could use for their (smaller) personal folders.

A paid tool is fine, if it works well.